# Multiply matrix and letter

Tags: matrices

I want to multiply a matrix with a letter, it looks like that:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \[ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 | &  & |  \\
f_1 & \dots & f_n \\
 | &  & | \end{array}\right)  \mathcal{A} =
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 | &  & |  \\
q_1 & \dots & q_n \\
 | &  & | \end{array} \right)\] 

\end{document}
```

Is there a chance, that the letter is not so small in comparison to the matrix, so that they have about the same size?

Comment: Via `graphicx` package, you can use `{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{\scalebox{3}{$\mathcal{A}$}}}` but the result would not look that nice I guess.

Comment: hm true, it looks strange. But thanks anyway. Maybe I will stick to my old variant.

Comment: It would maybe look better if you reduce the size of the matrices via `smallmatrix` variants.

Answer (score 5):

As percusse points out, you can resize it using the package `graphicx`:

```
{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{\scalebox{3}{$\mathcal{A}$}}}
```

However, I would say that it looks better "small" than "resized". That would be very inconsistent and weird. I recommend you to stuck with small $A$. However, there're few possible improvements of your code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \[ \begin{pmatrix}
 | &  & |  \\
f_1 & \cdots & f_n \\
 | &  & | \end{pmatrix}  \mathcal{A} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 | &  & |  \\
q_1 & \cdots & q_n \\
 | &  & | \end{pmatrix}\] 

\end{document}
```

- Do not use `ngerman` package, use `babel` with the appropriate option.
- The package `amsmath` offers the environment `pmatrix` for matrices in parentheses, as well as `bmatrix` for `[...]`, `Bmatrix` for `{...}`, `vmatrix` for `|...|` and `Vmatrix` for `||...||`.
- I'm not sure what the verical bars denote (probably a vector written in a column?) but I'm sure I would not understand it as a reader. However, I don't know how to improve it, since the context is missing. If the entries are really column vectors and you defined them properly before, I think that the reader would understand it even without the bars.